# Need more clarity on Definition Expressions

Tags: f#

What does this statement mean and why would I write code like that?

```
let id x = x in (id 3, id "Three")
```

> F# 3.0 spec: 6.6 Definition Expressions

Comment: This is really only used in the verbose syntax, which is pretty much unused at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

It defines identity function:

```
let id x = x
```

`in` this expression:

```
(id 3, id "Three")
```

so result of this expression is a tuple of type `(int * string):`

```
(3, "Three")
```

Edit:
You don't necessarily need to write code like this (maybe in very rare cases). By default F# uses `light` syntax without `in` like this:

```
let id x = x // Define the function
(id 3, id "Three") // Apply it to the elements of tuple
```

When you are using `verbose` syntax you don't have to follow whitespace indentation rules. Here it is described more clearly: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/

I believe verbose syntax is used mostly when you need to use `let` in a one line expression as in your sample

Comment: Thank you. But I am not that smart. Can you help me understand why I would write code like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
let v = expr in body
```

defines a new environment with the name `v` bound to `expr` and then evaluates `body` in the created environment. In this case `id` is defined to be a function of type `a -> a` which just returns its argument. The body

```
(id 3, id "Three")
```

is then evaluated with `id` bound to the above function.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not that smart. Can you help me understand why I would write code like that?

Answer (score 1):

If `id x = x` then a) `id 3 = 3` and b) `id "three" = "three"`. Put it together, in `(id 3, id "three")`, if we `let id x = x` then the result is that `(id 3, id "three") = (3, "three")`. That's the gist of it.